# Can't remove item from ObservableCollection through ContextMenu

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a program with a class called `MyClass` and `Location`. `MyClass` contains an `ObservableCollection` of `Location` items and `Location` contains a string property called `Name`. In `MainPage.xaml` I have a `LongListSelector` (with a `ContextMenu` for each item) populated with grids representing a `Location`.

When I click the 'remove' menu item from the context control, it will usually remove the underlying `Location` object and update the view. After a few cycles of populating the `LongListSelector` and removing all its items, some new items that are added can't be removed anymore.

Here's an example of what I mean: The LLS originally contains 2 items. Then I delete those 2 items and add 3 more. However, I can only remove the third one, in this case, but not the first 2.

Here's the `ContextMenu` `MenuItem` click event from `MainPage.xaml.cs`:

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var selectedItem = (sender as MenuItem).DataContext as Location;

    for (int i = 0; i < MyClass.Locations.Count; i++)
    {
        if (MyClass.Locations[i].Name == selectedItem.Name)
        {
            MyClass.Locations.Remove(MyClass.Locations[i]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Prior to using a `for` loop, I used this LINQ code and still had the same problem:

```
var toRemove = MyClass.Locations.Where(x => x.Name == selectedItem.Name).SingleOrDefault();
MyClass.Locations.Remove(toRemove);
```

Any suggestions to fix this problem?

Comment: I assume the DataContext is actually an Item from the Locations? In that case you should be able to remove the Items from the Collection with something like `MyClass.Locations.Remove(selectedItem)` instead of the for loop.

Comment: I have tried that, but I still had the same problem, unfortunately.

Comment: Can you elaborate the `can't be removed anymore` a bit better? Are you still able to open the context menu? Have you tried to set a breakpoint at the condition to see if the Name's aren't matching for whatever reason?

Comment: The ContextMenu still shows up. I set a breakpoint and it turns out `selectedItem` is null.

Comment: `var selectedItem = (sender as MenuItem).DataContext as Location;` will be null if either sender is not A Menu Item (but you should get a NullReferenceException in that case) or DataContext is not a Location. What is the DataContext for an Item where the selectedItem is null?

Comment: My bad, `selectedItem` is not null. It has the same name as the item that was deleted before the new item was added.

Comment: `<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.DataContext>
        <local:MyClass/>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.DataContext>`

Comment: @pcnThird - can you try to replace LLS with ListBox and check if you have the same problems?

Comment: Wow, I'm actually surprised using a ListBox worked! Thanks, Romasz. Feel free to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use a ListBox instead of LLS - if you are not using grouping option. It works much better and causes less problems.
By the way I've also encountered [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19356668/long-list-selector-observable-collection-and-visual-tree-problems) problems with this Control - maybe similar to yours.
 Weird is also that LLS.UpdateLayout() doesn't work while in ListBox works perfect.