# LongListMultiSelector does not refresh the 2nd element's view when the count of ItemsSource is THREE

Tags: windows-phone-8, binding, converters, longlistselector

Recently I was using `LongListMultiSelector`(LLMS) in WPToolkit and now facing a quite strange bug. That is, when the `ItemsSource` of the LLMS has exactly 3 items. Then the second one's view doesn't get refreshed, while the other two do. And the LLMS is all right when the count is other than 3. I wrote a small App to test the situation. In this test, a LLMS is binding to an `ObservableCollection<ItemViewModel>`. Here is the code of `ItemViewModel`:

```
public class ItemViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ItemViewModel()
    {
        time = DateTime.Now;
    }

    private DateTime _time;
    /// <summary>
    /// Property for test use
    /// </summary>
    public DateTime time
    {
        get { return _time; }
        set
        {
            if (_time != value)
            {
                _time = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("time");
            }
        }
    }

    #region INPC Impl
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string pName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(pName));
    }
    #endregion
}
```

And my LLMS is set like this:

```
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
        <local:ItemToStrConverter x:Key="cvt"></local:ItemToStrConverter>
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    ......
    <toolkit:LongListMultiSelector Height="300" Name="llms">
         <toolkit:LongListMultiSelector.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource cvt}}"
                            Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}"></TextBlock>
             </DataTemplate>
         </toolkit:LongListMultiSelector.ItemTemplate>
     </toolkit:LongListMultiSelector>
```

The `ItemToStrConverter` is something that converts an instance of `ItemViewModel` to string (`time.ToString()`).

Please do notice that the `Text` of `TextBlock` in the `DataTemplate` is not binding to `time`. Instead, it is binding to the `ItemViewModel` instance directly.

So let's say if the LLMS is on the `MainPage`, and I go to some other pages to modify an `ItemViewModel` instance's `time` and go back to `MainPage`, this will cause the LLMS to be loaded and new one or more `ItemToStrConverter` to convert. If I have more or less than 3 items, everything is fine, all the instances will be converted properly. However, when I have 3 items, the second one does not get converted. I made a breakpoint in the `Convert` method, and the bug is occuring because this method was only called twice (to the 1st and 3rd instance). It seems that the LLMS simply ignores the 2nd instance.

Has anybody met this problem before?

Comment: Yes, I've encountered similar problem with LLS, I haven't found the solution so far. I've [noticed that it may be connected with VisualTree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19356668/long-list-selector-observable-collection-and-visual-tree-problems). If you don't use grouping you may use ListBox instead of LLS - there are no such problems.

Comment: Sadly I need the Multi-Selection function. I've change my ItemViewModel to expose a Property that is used and updated particularly for the LLMS binding. I think this is a bug of LLMS :(